# onclick event doesn't work in span tag

Tags: javascript, onclick, onclicklistener

I just finished my javascript course in somewhere in online, and tried to make my own small project 'todolist'.

when user put work into  and click , list should be added, but it shows a white and clear page.. I really can't see what's the problem in here.

I tested using console.log() but It shows me what I want, but it doesn't works in tag.

Here is my Code :

```css
input[type=text] {
  width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
}

#input_table {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#input_box {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: crimson;
}

.align_center {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.submit_box {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  color: #555;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: gold;
}

.input_text {
  float: left;
}

.store_ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.oneLine {
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.close_box {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  color: #555;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <title>ToDoList</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var count = 50;
    var i = 0;
    var tag = '';
  </script>
  <div id="input_table">
    <div id="input_box">
      <h1 style="color:white">My To Do List</h1>
      <div class="align_center">
        <input class="text_box" type="text" value="Title...">
        <span class="submit_box" onclick="write()">Add</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="output_table">
    <div class="store_box">
      <ul class="store_ul">

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    function write() {
      var text = document.querySelector('.text_box').value;
      console.log(text);
      if (i < 50) {
        tag += '<div class="oneLine"><li class="input_text">' + text + '</li><span class="close_box">x</span></div>';
        document.querySelector('.store_ul').innerHTML = tag;
        console.log(tag);
        i++;
      } else {
        alert("lists can't be added more than 50 works");
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Why is the parent of an li a div and not a ul?

Comment: If you change your function name to be something other than write, it will work.

Comment: @epascarello You should post that as an answer and explain why, unless you can find a duplicate.

Comment: I been looking for a dupe, should be a common problem.

Comment: Yeah! I finally found function name write() is a problem in my codes. Thankyou for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`write` will refer to the global function `document.write`, which will completely replace the page if the page has already been loaded. Use a different function name, perhaps "addTodo":

It would also probably be better to use a *placeholder* rather than a hard-coded *value* of `Title...` in the input box:

```js
var count = 50;
var i = 0;
var tag = '';

function addTodo() {
  var text = document.querySelector('.text_box').value;
  console.log(text);
  if (i < 50) {
    tag += '<div class="oneLine"><li class="input_text">' + text + '</li><span class="close_box">x</span></div>';
    document.querySelector('.store_ul').innerHTML = tag;
    console.log(tag);
    i++;
  } else {
    alert("lists can't be added more than 50 works");
  }
}
```

```css
input[type=text] {
  width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
}

#input_table {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#input_box {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: crimson;
}

.align_center {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.submit_box {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  color: #555;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: gold;
}

.input_text {
  float: left;
}

.store_ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.oneLine {
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.close_box {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  color: #555;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <title>ToDoList</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
  </script>
  <div id="input_table">
    <div id="input_box">
      <h1 style="color:white">My To Do List</h1>
      <div class="align_center">
        <input class="text_box" type="text" placeholder="Title...">
        <span class="submit_box" onclick="addTodo()">Add</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="output_table">
    <div class="store_box">
      <ul class="store_ul">

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Thankyou for answering my question! I've never known about placeholder! Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

You have a name conflict and the native method overrides yours in the global scope. In the example below you can see it is document.write.

```html
<button onclick="console.log(write)">console</button>
<button onclick="console.log(write('hi'))">Hi</button>
```